# AND condition in WHERE clause on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
Table 1 = restaurants ( r_id , type , cuisine_bkup ) 
Table 2 = address ( id , r_id , location, address )
```

I am applying this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM restaurants r 
RIGHT JOIN addresses a ON a.r_id = r.r_id 
WHERE r.type LIKE 'Cafe' AND a.location LIKE 'Gulberg' AND  r.cuisine_bkup LIKE 'Pizza'
GROUP BY r.r_id
```

Its giving me no result what should i do i want to do it with AND condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%` with `like`

```
WHERE r.type LIKE '%Cafe%' 
AND a.location LIKE '%Gulberg%' 
AND  r.cuisine_bkup LIKE '%Pizza%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need the wildcard character `%` to search the values in your column like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM restaurants r 
RIGHT JOIN addresses a ON a.r_id = r.r_id 
WHERE r.type LIKE '%Cafe%' AND a.location LIKE '%Gulberg%' AND  r.cuisine_bkup LIKE '%Pizza%'
GROUP BY r.r_id
```

else the other option(*which I am guessing is to use an **OR** instead of **AND***)

```
SELECT * 
FROM restaurants r 
RIGHT JOIN addresses a ON a.r_id = r.r_id 
WHERE r.type LIKE '%Cafe%' OR a.location LIKE '%Gulberg%' OR r.cuisine_bkup LIKE '%Pizza%'
GROUP BY r.r_id
```

(***Also to note that you will get the result for your AND when and only when all the three conditions are TRUE ie, `r.type LIKE 'Cafe' AND a.location LIKE 'Gulberg' AND  r.cuisine_bkup LIKE 'Pizza'`***)

Comment: I would expect the original is correct - searching for a Café in Gulberg that serves Pizza - so all three required to be true - not getting a list of Cafes regardless of location/cuisine + list of all restuarants in Gulberg + list of all restaurants serving Pizza.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I found the solution after 5 minutes f posting this question ...... And you're absolutely right , it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM restaurants r 
RIGHT JOIN addresses a ON a.r_id = r.r_id AND a.location LIKE 'Gulberg'
WHERE r.type LIKE 'Cafe'  AND  r.cuisine_bkup LIKE 'Pizza'
GROUP BY r.r_id
```

To make RIGHT join work , you have to move `AND a.location LIKE 'Gulberg'` to `ON` section.Otherwise it will function as `INNER JOIN`.

I would like to point out that '=' will work much faster than `LIKE`(If you are equating characters)..

Hope this helps